# How to block the DNS query on DNS server from Windows machine

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, windows-server-2008-r2

We have windows 7 machine which was on domain(Windows 2008 server) but Now We have to remove the Windows server from network and we can't remove the domain from client machine.

Setup the another DNS filter(nxfilter) for block a web site and which ip set on all client machine as DNS.

Problem is that, On the nxfilter, get too many domain request like *nserver.corp.abc.com*, *wpad.corp.abc.com*, _ldap.*tcp.dc.abc.com* etc. How to prevent those request from client? I think, we can add the entry in *HOSTS file* but I need to find another way...

Comment: "we can't remove the domain from client machine" Why not? This is the real problem you need to fix.

Comment: @DavidPostill Because Profile contain many user setting, So that we con't want to change it. How to prevent domain DNS query ?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent those DNS queries from your clients? Just don't want to see them on your log-view of NxFilter GUI? Or you really want to block it? If it's the first one you can bypass logging for them on 'Whitelist > Domain'. Or you can set up a local DNS server for those domains to bypass them to your local DNS server.

Comment: Yes, I want to block  DNS queries from windows client(goal is querie can't be reached on nxfilter) because getting too much  queries of domain name(may be decrease performance of Nxfilter as well as windows machine).

Comment: Do you really experience a performance issue? We see many sites having more than sevral thousands users but they don't complain about the performance. Maybe you just need to bypass logging for them as NxFilter spends the biggest resource for logging.